# firebase didnt add data using flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

the url showing error giving me cast error. i am using realtime database and i also use

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Products": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }

  }
}
```

when i add data the data is being saved in the app but post request didn't save it in the firebase
i creating this app form acedemine course.
The URL is correct .The URL is accessible from your my location or network.The server is running or maintenance. i want to  resolve this issue,

```
  import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import './product.dart';

class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = [
    Product(
      id: 'p1',
      title: 'Red Shirt',
      description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
      price: 29.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p2',
      title: 'Trousers',
      description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
      price: 59.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p3',
      title: 'Yellow Scarf',
      description: 'Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.',
      price: 19.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p4',
      title: 'A Pan',
      description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
      price: 49.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg',
    ),
  ];
 

  List<Product> get items {
 
    return [..._items];
  }

  List<Product> get favoriteItems {
    return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
  }

  get id => null;

  Product findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }



  void addProduct(Product product) {
    const url =
        "https://flutter-update-'this place is hide by me'firebasedatabase.app/Products.json";
    http.post(
      url ,
      body: json.encode({
        'title ': product.title,
        'description': product.description,
        'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
        'price': product.price,
        'isFavorite': product.isFavorite
      }),
    );

    final newProduct = Product(
      title: product.title,
      description: product.description,
      price: product.price,
      imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    );
    _items.add(newProduct);

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateProduct(String id, Product newProduct) {
    final prodIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    if (prodIndex >= 0) {
      _items[prodIndex] = newProduct;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      print('...');
    }
  }

  void deleteProduct(String id) {
    _items.removeWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your database security rules require that there is an authenticated user (`"auth != null"`) in order to access the data.

But in your `http.post` call you don't specify any authentication credentials, which means that it is an anonymous user. So the security rules correctly reject that request.

To make `http.post` call come from an authenticated user, you'll need to pass a token as shown in the documentation on [authenticating REST requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth).

Comment: sir, I swear that I respect your reputation. Thank you again, sir. you are our father programmer but your answer didn't solve my issues. I search this issue in the chatgpt and it solves my issue. your American engineer but this does not work here.

Comment: (no swearing to things is needed)

If you can't get authentication to work over the REST call, show what you tried. That is the documented approach to work against the rules you posted.

What you posted as an answerworks too, but means that everyone in the world can read/write your entire database which is a bad idea. Seriously: with a single line of code they can wipe you entire database. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: ok, sir next time I will follow the documentation. I learning from one of the udemy course. if I apply the documentation process then the code would be stuck. again thank you for your replay, I always watch your videos on youtube. you are our great mentor hope your life will be longer.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is not allowing post requests using external packages such as `http`. You should instead use the `firebase_database` api. Link for the documentation here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/start

Comment: but i am learning for acdememind course they post data into it using http.

Comment: "Firebase is not allowing post requests using external packages such as `http`" While I'd also typically recommend using the Firebase SDKs, the Realtime Database **does** have a REST API that can be called through `http`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start

Comment: thank you, bro, it worked has I expected.